# MailKit.Security.AuthenticationException: '535: Authentication Failed'

Tags: c#, smtp, mailkit

I am facing Authentication issue from MailKit with correct credentials., issue:'535: Authentication Failed'

```
        var message = new MimeMessage();
        message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("noreply", "noreply@xyz@gmail.com"));
        message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("xyz", "xyz@gmail.com"));
        message.Subject = "Test Email";
        message.Body = new TextPart("html")
        {
            Text = "Test email sent successfully."
        };
        
        var client = new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient();
        try
        {
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
            client.SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12;
            client.Connect("smtp.zeptomail.in", 587, false);
            client.Authenticate("emailapikey", password);
            client.Send(message);
            client.Disconnect(true);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Write(e.Message);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you have an API key, then you need to use that as the password and not use it as the username.

Where is the documentation for your email server and what does it say about using API keys for authentication?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you need to add acces to less secure applications,
its simply:

1. add two steps verification
2. Create & use App Passwords

follow this link...
[Sign in with App Passwords](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en)